# Android: ExpandableListView child item click works on multiple children

Tags: android

I am trying to implement an expandable list view in android. The child element contains **two image views** among others. By clicking on these I update the number displayed on each child element. **The problem** I am facing is that clicking on a particular child also updates the values of other random children in both the same as well as different parent.

My Adapter:

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private ArrayList<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
    // child data in format of header title, child title
    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<FoodItem>> _listDataChild;

    public MenuAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> listDataHeader,
                       HashMap<String, ArrayList<FoodItem>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final FoodItem child = (FoodItem) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_menu, null);
        }

        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        TextView priceTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
        final TextView quantityTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.quantityTextView);
        ImageView decreaseImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.decreaseImageView);
        ImageView increaseImageView = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.increaseImageView);

        nameTextView.setText(child.getName());
        priceTextView.setText(child.getPrice());

        decreaseImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (child.getCount() > 0) {
                    quantityTextView.setText(Integer.toString(child.getCount() - 1));
                    child.setCount(child.getCount() - 1);
                }
            }
        });
        increaseImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                quantityTextView.setText(Integer.toString(child.getCount() + 1));
                child.setCount(child.getCount() + 1);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.header_menu, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.headerTextView);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to set the initial value for `quantityTextView`
add this your `getChildView()`

```
quantityTextView.setText(Integer.toString(child.getCount()));
```

EDIT:
the reason why it seems to happen randomly is that the views are getting reused, that means convertView isn't `null`. It will display whatever was displayed in that convertView (might be any View scrolled off the screen in no particular order) if you don't reset/set initial values.

P.S. You should really look into the holder pattern [link](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a bunch!